# Unable to create shadow on UIButton with white background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have tried to assign shadow to UIButton with the help of following code :

```
self.addCardButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.addCardButton.layer.shadowOffset =CGSizeZero;
self.addCardButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.addCardButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.addCardButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
self.addCardButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
self.addCardButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
self.addCardButton.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

In viewdidload().
Still getting zero results.... please help me in knowing possible reasons for this glitch.

Comment: add this code into viewdidlayoutsubviews and check

Comment: try this in viewwillapper or viewdidappear

Comment: Try this code in viewDidAppear , also for testing comment `cornerRadius` line

Comment: reason : your view is not loaded fully

Comment: Also I used the same code on other screens in viewdidload() ... strangely it worked fine.